# Neat way to apply a function to every nth element of a sequence?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

What's a neat way to map a function to every nth element in a sequence ? Something like `(map-every-nth fn coll n)`, so that it would return the original sequence with only every nth element transformed, e.g. (map-every-nth inc (range 16) 4) would return (0 1 2 4 4 5 6 8 8 9 10 12 12 13 14 16)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
(defn map-every-nth [f coll n]
  (map-indexed #(if (zero? (mod (inc %1) n)) (f %2) %2) coll))

(map-every-nth inc (range 16) 4)
> (0 1 2 4 4 5 6 8 8 9 10 12 12 13 14 16)
```

Comment: thanks I realized how trivial it was and how I'd done it before shortly after posting it!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that this would be simpler and cleaner than the accepted answer:

```
(defn map-every-nth [f coll n]
  (map f (take-nth n coll)))
```

This is a handy one to know: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/take-nth

Comment: nearly! that would only return the nth members of coll, whereas I asked for the whole coll with every nth mapped through f, so: (defn map-every-nth [f coll n] (mapcat cons (map f (take-nth n coll)) (map rest (partition n coll)) ))

Comment: => (map-every-nth inc (range 16) 4)
(1 1 2 3 5 5 6 7 9 9 10 11 13 13 14 15)   ; cheers! your alternative lead to a nice solution!

Comment: oops! just noticed I'm an element off there...oh! take-nth starts at zero...not what I'd expect but the principle's the same

Comment: Oh, I see... sorry, this answer was not exactly what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like this solution better:

```
(defn apply-to-last [f col] (concat (butlast col) (list (f (last col)))))
(apply concat (map #(apply-to-last (fn [x] (* 2 x)) %) (partition 4 (range 16))))
```

Or as a function:

```
(defn apply-to-last [f col] (concat (butlast col) (list (f (last col)))))
(defn map-every-nth [f col n] (apply concat (map #(apply-to-last f %) (partition n col))))
(map-every-nth (fn [x] (* 2 (inc x))) (range 16) 4)
; output: (0 1 2 8 4 5 6 16 8 9 10 24 12 13 14 32)
```

Notice this easily leads to the ability to `apply-to-first`, `apply-to-second` or `apply-to-third` giving the ability to control the "start" of mapping every nth element.

I do not know the performance of the code I wrote above, but it does seem more idiomatic to me.